# Pagination with PHP

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I am trying to run the pagination code I created, but I can't figure out how to get all items from table separated to pages(pagination).

Following is the code.

```
public function getCatItemsByPage($cat, $page) {
    $query = "SELECT 
                id
              FROM 
                categories
              WHERE
                name = '$cat'";


    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $id = mysql_result($result, 0, "id");


 if($page == 1){
    $limit_start = 0;
    $limit_stop = 52;
 }else if($page == 2){
    $limit_start = ($page - 1) * 52;
    $limit_stop = $limit_start + 52; 
 }else{
    $limit_start = $page * 52;
    $limit_stop = $limit_start + 52; 
 }

    $output_videos_query = "SELECT 
               *
              FROM 
                videos
              WHERE
                cate_id=$id
              ORDER BY
                created_at
              DESC LIMIT 
                $limit_start, $limit_stop";

    $output_videos_result = mysql_query($output_videos_query) or die(mysql_error());

    return $output_videos_result;

}
```

I pass category($cat) and page number($page). And the problem is how to calculate $limit_start and $limit_stop by page. I spent last hour trying to figure out how to get videos, but some pages don't get some videos or some pages get lots of videos.

As I am new to PHP any idea on this, really appreciated.

Comment: start = Items_per_page * page
stop = start + Items_per_page

With page starting at 0
So at page 1 u'r offset will be :
0 * 52 = 52
page  2 = 1 * 52 = 52
page 3 = 2 * 52 = 104
And so on

Comment: Simple php pagination script : http://allitstuff.com/php-mysql-pagination-script-download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($page == 1){
    $limit_start = 0;
    $limit_stop = 52;
}else if($page == 2){
    $limit_start = ($page - 1) * 52;
    $limit_stop = $limit_start + 52; 
}else{
    $limit_start = $page * 52;
    $limit_stop = $limit_start + 52; 
}
```

What should this condition do? Simply do every time:

```
$limit_start = ($page - 1) * 52; // 0 when 1, 52 when 2, 104 when 3 etc.
$limit_stop = 52;
```

And it should work.

`$limit_stop` has to be a constant value as MySQL's LIMIT expects a length, not a position.

Comment: This actually works. I was beating around the bush. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this:

```
if($page == 1){
    $limit_start = 0;
    $limit_stop = 52;
}else if($page == 2){
    $limit_start = ($page - 1) * 52;
    $limit_stop = $limit_start + 52; 
}else{
    $limit_start = $page * 52;
    $limit_stop = $limit_start + 52; 
}
```

With a much simpler:

```
$limit_start = ($page - 1) * 52;
$limit_stop = 52;
```

Comment: Mh, sorry. I didn't think so far because your answer was styled the same^^

Comment: I'd probably assume that's because it's the most readable stylistic way to format it (and also matches nearly all PHP coding standards). :P

Comment: No, I mean the layout: copying the problem, writing a sentence, write short solution.^^